# Multithreaded 2d array input failing to produce output using pthreads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I created code to create a 2D table with threads but it won't run and I can't find a solution to this (I'm new to threads, and sorry for my bad English).

```
#include <pthread.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_barrier_t our_barrier;
int done = 2;

void *threadfunc2(void *k) {
    if (done != (int)*(int*)k) {
        int n, d, i, j;
        printf("give the  2d table dimensions \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);    
        scanf("%d", &d);
        int array[n][d];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < d; j++){
                printf("%d", array[i][j]);
            }
        }

        pthread_barrier_wait(&our_barrier);
        printf("Now finished!!!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    int k = 1;
    pthread_t  tid1;
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadfunc2, (void *)&k);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to ask me to give the numbers for the 2D table but it won't do anything.

Comment: You have to join thread `pthread_join(tid1,NULL);` to wait until it is completed.

Comment: @rafix07 is correct. Currently the thread is being created but the entire process is destroyed and the thread with it. Add `pthread_join(tid1, NULL);` right after `pthread_create()`

Comment: It might help to explain what this program is trying to do beyond collect input for the 2d matrix. I don't see any point to making this multithreaded as it stands.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  The compiler says: "...:32:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"  The function being questioned is the thread function.  Please fix and re-post

Comment: Every exit point from a thread function 'should' be calling: `pthread_exit()` not `return` nor just running off the end of the function

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  As an example: `if( scanf("%d", &d) != 1) { // handle error }`   Note: those functions return the number of successful input format conversions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment `main()` returns, the process ends and the OS tears down all other threads belonging to the same process.

There are several options to avoid this behaviour:

- Join the thread created in `main()` by calling `pthread_join()`.
- Leave `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()`.
- Make `main()` block until the thread spawned off did its work by using a set of condition- mutex- and status-variables.